# jQuery: multiple 'tipsy' tool tips

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tipsy

When I bring back a list of results from my database, they are displayed like so:

> Result 1
>   Result 2
>   Result 3

And so on... Now I've got the jQuery Tipsy plugin working so when you hover over the top of Result 1 it shows that persons users name. The thing is, if I hover over Result 2, that too should have the Tipsy tooltip appear, but it is just displaying the normal browsers tooltip.

I'm assuming it's because all the `id`'s on the results `a` tag's are name the same: 'east'. I guess I need to make some sort of for each check in the jQuery yet I wouldn't have the foggiest on where to add this in the jQuery.

Has anyone got a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is having the same ID on all 3 `a` tags. Under no circumstance is it acceptable to have the same ID applied to more than one element on the same page. You'll need to fix that.

```
<a href="result_one.html" id="result_one" class="tipsy">Result 1</a>
<a href="result_two.html" id="result_two" class="tipsy">Result 2</a>
<a href="result_three.html" id="result_three" class="tipsy">Result 3</a>
```

You can apply the same class to all three `a` tags and then apply tipsy to the class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tipsy').tipsy({fade:true,gravity:'n'});
});
```

Or you can do each ID separately.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#result_one').tipsy({fade:true,gravity:'n'});
  $('#result_two').tipsy({fade:true,gravity:'n'});
  $('#result_three').tipsy({fade:true,gravity:'n'});
});
```

Comment: I don't quite follow, sorry! I've changed id='east' on the a link to class='east' but I'm unsure what I changed in the jquery, the only bit that I understand is getting anything from an ID is the line $('#east').tipsy({gravity: 'e'}); so I changed that to $('.east').tipsy({gravity: 'e'}); but it doesn't work. I'm probably going completely the wrong way about it :S

Comment: Be certain you have your jQuery called after the DOM is ready. I've updated my code to show this check.

Comment: It was already being called after the DOM was ready. I've figured out what I was doing wrong. Your answer was correct, it was something elseI was doing wrong. I had 2 class attributes in my a tag which was causing the problem. Joined them both together and it is working fine. Thank you very much for your help!